# What is the fastest and easiest way to insert data into MySQL / MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, import, mariadb

I have a table called `discounts`.

```
CREATE TABLE discounts (
 id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 expired_date DATE NOT NULL,
 amount DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I need to insert more than one million from the backend. If I run via insert query it took long time to execute in my MariaDB server.

Is there a simplest way to execute query like import data from text file or SQL file?

Comment: You should really look into documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loading-tables.html

Comment: thank you. i got the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open notepad, type the following content in it.

```
/* give tab inbetween the columns */
Spring Break 2014   20140101    20 
Back to School  20140901    25
Summer 2014 20140825    10
```

and save the file in c drive as .sql or .txt file format.

Open MariaDB / mysql and paste the following code

```
use test;   /* here test is the database name */
/* i save the file path in c:/ drive */
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/sample.sql'  /* here sample if the file name  */
INTO TABLE discounts COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t' /* \t it will truncate the tab */
(title, expired_date, amount);
```

*execute the query.*

*It will execute unlimited number of records.*

Comment: If you going to run the above query in your MySQL / MariaDB server, you have to me mention like **LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql/sample.sql'.** code instead.